# Know how long one or more keys are pressed Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. This is normal text
   I would like to know how I can get a bool to turn on if I have one key pressed, if I have two, another bool turns on with both keys pressed, and the first turns off and so on.

So far I have my code, but if I press the first key and I press the second, it detects both.

```
enter code here


[Serializable]
public class KeyCodeEvent : UnityEvent<KeyCode>
public bool KeyPresed;
public bool KeyPresed2;
public bool KeyPresed3;

public KeyCodeEvent keyDownListener, keyUpListener, keyPressListener;

private static readonly KeyCode[] keyCodes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode))
    .Cast<KeyCode>()
    .Where(k => ((int)k < (int)KeyCode.Mouse0))
    .ToArray();
private List<KeyCode> _keysDown;

public void OnEnable()
{
    _keysDown = new List<KeyCode>();
}
public void OnDisable()
{
    _keysDown = null;
}
public void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keyCodes.Length; i++)
    {
        KeyCode kc1 = keyCodes[i];
        KeyCode kc2 = keyCodes[i];
        if (Input.GetKey(kc1))
        {
            _keysDown.Add(kc1);
            keyDownListener?.Invoke(kc1);
            Debug.Log(kc1);
            KeyPresed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well you have methods to say a key went down in a frame. And a key went up in a frame.  Time between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of your key pressed times in a dictionary. Just create a field `Dictionary<KeyCode, float> keyHoldTimes` and initialize it on enable. Then change update method into this:

```cs
void Update(){
    for (int i = 0; i < keyCodes.Length; i++)
    {
        KeyCode kc1 = keyCodes[i];
        if (Input.GetKey(kc1))
        {
            keyHoldTimes[kc1] += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            keyHoldTimes[kc1] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a `SortedDictionary` and then you know the order in which the keys where pressed (the one with longest hold time was pressed first).